# Always get HTTP Error 500 from MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, php-parse-error

If I try to open a php page with a any error inside, the browser always show me "HTTP ERROR 500"; so I have to look at the error log to have better informations about what's wrong with the code. 
Is it possible to change some MAMP setting, so a more specific error will be displayed instead of the "error 500"?

I mean, if I wrote

```
<?php
ech1o "hello";
```

the browser should show me:

> [18-Jun-2016 15:05:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
>   unexpected '"hello"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Examples/000.php on line 3

and not just

> HTTP ERROR 500

The problem is specifically about MAMP setup and not about PHP in general. If I write the same code with EasyPHP on Windows, the browser show me the line where there's an error.

Comment: ech1o? it should be `echo "hello";`

Comment: `<?php echo "hello" ?>`

Comment: I think you have this already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @Ray; I know that is not correct "ech1o", but the question is about "errors in MAMP", if I write "echo" there is not errors to manage...

Comment: Check MAMP's logs. there must be an internal server error (HTTP ERROR 500)

Comment: @Ray it's an evident "parse error" as shown in the log, but the browser always show me "internal server error". Please read the full text of my question.